# How to validate MOSS Installation

Tags: 2007

How to validate MOSS Installation.. 
One of my colleague is asking for above. Having MOSS application development experience I understand validation should be requirement specific. And also on where and how I am using it?

I know it's enough to have central administration in place to validate at least it is installed.

Still I am asking; what are the other key things I need to check in general scenario. Which may remain unnoticed in certain situation, but still may be a key factor for a problem.

Thanks in Advance 
Rajdip

Answer (score 1):

I asked similar question here in the context of a restore:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077021/verify-sharepoint-restore

SharePoint is so dynamic in nature that you will have to create a checklist that reflects your own architecture. I would start by inspecting the server logs - one of the more common issues is not having the required security accounts in place prior to installation. Also, I believe that there is a tool to check for problems with the 2010 release.

Comment: Thanks IrishChieftain.
Even if issue is with MOSS 2007; I will have a look in the tool you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a big question without knowing anything about your environment.

Some key points are:
 - Service accounts.  How many are you using?
 - SSP - is it configured?
 - Search - is it working? How is it distributed (index, query, crawler).
 - Profiles - are they being pulled from AD?

As for usage.  SharePoint can get out of control, so a good governance plan is essential.
 - Site collections v sites
 - Security
 - Content Ownership

Sorry, this is a litle rushed, but hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Donaldinio.. It helps as you validated what I said to my colleague :)
I asked him to come up with a specific requirement.